# How to get data from form with spark java?

Tags: java, post, spark-java

I'm pretty new with all these things but hope that you guys can help me understand how does it work.
I got a form with field . How do i get data from client back? Was looking for some information but couldnt find.

```
<form action="Dispatcher" method="post">
    <fieldset>
        <p>Name</p>
        <input type="text" name="userName" required="true">

        <p>Email</p>
        <input type="text" name="userEmail" required="true">
        <input type="submit" value="submit">
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Did any of the answers work for you?

Answer (score 20):

I faced the same issue. I used `queryParams` to solve it:

```
request.queryParams("userName")
```

Comment: Note you have to ensure that `request.body()` is not invoked beforehand (for logging purpose for example), otherwise it consumes the body, the form param won't be parsed. The javadoc is quite lacking on that matter.

Comment: This is weird. I was expecting request.params("userName") to return the value but instead request.queryParams("userName") gives the same value. I thought queryParams was supposed to return query strings. Is this normal behaviour of java spark?

Comment: @Raf **Is this normal behaviour of java spark?** You name it: this is a *weird* behaviour of java spark.

Comment: @Stephan thanks, your answer saved me. I wanted to test microservice and I have done it kind of differently than most tests example available online, can you please have a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37715875/testing-java-spark-microservices-app-that-implements-sparkapplication-interface , your feedback would be appreciated.

Comment: As mentioned by @Raf earlier I expected request.params("userName") to work as well. But request.queryParams("userName") has actually worked for me and I do not understand why. If anyone can explain please add.

A piece if additional information I am testing this form submission using Postman and only "x-www-form-urlencoded" request work. Post requests set to "form-data" on Postman do not work.

Comment: `queryParams` delegates to the underlying HTTP infrastructure's `Request::getParameter` (see https://github.com/perwendel/spark/blob/master/src/main/java/spark/Request.java#L292). That methods docs explain "Returns the value of a request parameter as a String, or null if the parameter does not exist. Request parameters are extra information sent with the request. For HTTP servlets, parameters are contained in the query string or posted form data." https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameter-java.lang.String-

Answer (score 5):

Just for the record, I faced a similar problem and this how I solved it.

Since it is a multipart request, you will have to specify that

```
MultipartConfigElement multipartConfigElement = new MultipartConfigElement(path);

req.raw().setAttribute("org.eclipse.jetty.multipartConfig", multipartConfigElement);
```

You can find the details here [SparkJava: Upload file did't work in Spark java framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34746900/sparkjava-upload-file-didt-work-in-spark-java-framework)

Once this is done correctly you should be able to [access the data using query params](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32491399/363573) as mentioned Stephan.

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to use `request.params("userName")` which will give you the list of parameters submitted with name `userName`

Comment: Weird naming convention. Should have made it much more obvious: `getPostParam`

Answer (score 1):

As [Java doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameter-java.lang.String-) says,

> If the parameter data was sent in the request body, such as occurs with an HTTP POST request, then reading the body directly via getInputStream() or getReader() can interfere with the execution of this method.

So `request.queryParams("userName")` won't work after calling `request.body()` (for logging for instance). I wrote a utility function to get parameter.

```
public static String getParameter(String body, String param) {
    HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap();
    for (String s : body.split("&")) {
        String[] kv = s.split("=");
        params.put(kv[0], kv[1]);
    }
    String encoded = params.get(param);
    return URLDecoder.decode(encoded, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
}
```

Answer (score -3):

I think you'd better use a js framework like AngularJS or JQuery to convert form data into json before sending it to the server.