# Java Spark REST api upload file

Tags: java, spark-java

I'm working with java using java-spark to create the Rest Api and I'm having trouble figuring out how to receive a file so then I can process it. Haven't found anything as like in Spring that handles `MultipartFile`. Also this proyect is ran on a Tomcat server.

Answer (score 2):

As per the [official documentation](http://sparkjava.com/documentation#how-do-i-upload-something), the following code you get you started:

```
post("/yourUploadPath", (request, response) -> {
    request.attribute("org.eclipse.jetty.multipartConfig", new MultipartConfigElement("/temp"));
    try (InputStream is = request.raw().getPart("uploaded_file").getInputStream()) {
        // Use the input stream to create a file
    }
    return "File uploaded";
});
```

Comment: I used this config on the documentation and I cant seem to get it working I keep getting a null pointer since .getPart() is null. I'm not receiving the file from a form

Comment: Oh, sorry I did not see you were running on Tomcat. Would this other Q/A be helpful to you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40932829/spark-java-unable-to-process-parts-as-no-multi-part-configuration-has-been-prov