# Issue with Tomcat and parsing MultipartFile Upload service

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, multipartform-data, tomcat9

I have an app with an endpoint and a tomcat server running with it.  I can hit an endpoint on postman with a file and have it uploaded to an excel file on my server.

The problem is in order to get it to work I have to  add  allowCasualMultipartParsing="true" in the context.xml of my tomcat I don't want to have to add this fix on my local tomcat.

I need a fix that will work despite the tomcat server it's running on. So if someone were to add a new tomcat they wouldn't have this issue. For example on tomcat 9.0.6

Its hard to demonstrate the issue because it's due to running the app on a standalone tomcat.  It works when I run it without the standalone tomcat 9.0.38 .

Code for uploading file

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/ListCtrl")
public class listController {
    
    @RequestMapping(method = {RequestMethod.POST}, value = "/list")
    @Consumes (MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    @Produces (MediaType.TEXT_XML)
    @ResponseBody public Map<String, Object> uploadFile(
        @FormDataParam("file") InputStream uploadedInputStream,
        @FormDataParam("file") MultipartFile file,
        @RequestParam("listName") String listName,
        @RequestParam Integer
        listid){
        Map<String, Object> resultMap =  null;
        resultMap = new HashMap<>();
        resultMap.put("status", "successful");
        resultMap.put("file", file.getName());
        System.out.println(file.getOriginalFilename());
    return resultMap;
    }
```

The error I'm getting on the project that isn't working is
HTTP Status 500 - Could not parse multipart servlet request; nested exception is java. lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to process parts as no multi-part configuration has been provided

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution. I've seen it before but didn't fully understand so I wanted to elaborate here in case anyone else sees it. This solution will work despite the tomcat its running on.
You need to create a META-INF folder. For me I created under a deployed resources folder and I added a context.xml. After I put allowCasualMultipartParsing="true" in the context tag.
Webapp/Deployed Resources/META-INF/context.xml.

[Spark Java: Unable to process parts as no multi-part configuration has been provided](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40932829/spark-java-unable-to-process-parts-as-no-multi-part-configuration-has-been-prov)

Answer (score 0):

It is enough if you provide a configuration. As it has been mentioned in the spring documentation, there are two concrete implementations included in Spring.

1. [CommonsMultipartResolver](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/multipart/commons/CommonsMultipartResolver.html) for Apache Commons FileUpload and
2. [StandardServletMultipartResolver](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/multipart/support/StandardServletMultipartResolver.html) for the Servlet 3.0+ Part API

For better flexibility and configurabilities sake, I choose to use CommonsMultipartResolver. Among the advantages, it provides *maxUploadSize*, *maxInMemorySize*, and *defaultEncoding* settings as bean properties. But, you have to import it as:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.3</version>
</dependency>
```

And in your code:

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig {
    private int maxUploadSizeInMb = 2 * 1024 * 1024; // 2 MB
    ...
    ...
    @Bean("multipartResolver")
    public CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
        CommonsMultipartResolver cmr = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
        cmr.setMaxUploadSize(maxUploadSizeInMb * 2); //sum size of all files/parts of a file. Since, a file may be partitioned
        cmr.setMaxUploadSizePerFile(maxUploadSizeInMb);//maximum file size of each file
        return cmr;

    }
}
```

Comment: Getting this error when I try this.  I  also don't get this btw are you configuring the MultipartFile object i'm passing in through the input with this code?org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'multipartResolver' defined in com.fidelity.fcm.fpw.web.controller.HotListsCtrl: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception. Failed to instantiate Factory method 'multipartResolver' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/fileupload/FileItemFactory

Comment: sorry for the less detailed answer. I have updated it to give you the idea better. though I, didnt cover the `StandardServletMultipartResolver`

Comment: This question/answer is not about Apache Commons FileUpload. It's about the Servlet 3.0 builtin multipart/form-data parse

Comment: Like I said, you can choose one since they are the 2 concrete implementations included as of Spring 3.1. https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/multipart/MultipartResolver.html