# Testing Java Spark Microservices app that implements SparkApplication interface

Tags: unit-testing, junit, java-8, microservices, spark-java

I am trying to figure out how to test a web/rest services written in `Java Spark` and there is not many tutorials on how to do that. It is tricky to find answers due to confusion between `Apache Spark` and `Java Spark`.

I came across this [resource](https://github.com/perwendel/spark/tree/master/src/test/java/spark/servlet) but, I couldn't get it to work the way I had expected. There is also this [resource](https://github.com/mscharhag/blog-examples/tree/master/sparkdemo) and examples in `Java Spark` [github](https://github.com/perwendel/spark/tree/master/src/test/java/spark) but they all probably use embedded server.

Anyway, Assuming that I have the following service

```
public class RestService implements SparkApplication {
    @Override
    public void init() {
        get("/", (req, res) -> "Hello World!"); 
    }
}
```

I would like to test the above to make sure it `Hello World!` for `HTTP GET` requests or not. I have the following test:

```
public class RestServiceTest {
    //not sure if this is a good practice????
    final static RestService restService = new RestService(); 

    @BeforeClass
    public static void beforeClass() {
        //I have seen tests that invoked className.main(null)
        //but, I don't know if its good idea to do it here?
        restService.init();
        Spark.awaitInitialization();
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void afterClass() {
        Spark.stop();
    }

    @Test
    public void testRootRoute() throws IOException {
        TestResponse res = makeRequest("GET", "/");
        assertEquals(200, res.status);
        assertNotNull(res.body); 
        assertEquals("Hello World!", res.body);
    }

    private TestResponse makeRequest(String method, String path) throws IOException {
        URL url = new URL("http://localhost:4567" + path);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod(method);
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.connect();
        String body = IOUtils.toString(connection.getInputStream());
        return new TestResponse(connection.getResponseCode(), body);
    }

    private static class TestResponse {
        public final String body;
        public final int status;

        public TestResponse(int status, String body) {
            this.status = status;
            this.body = body;
        }
    }
}
```

Running the above, the test executes successfully aand the output is shown below but, my main concern is whether this is the right method of testing a `Java Spark` webapp aimed to run not in embedded server (when SparkApplication is implemented and `init()` is overrided)?

```
T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running com.company.test.RestServiceTest
[Thread-0] INFO org.eclipse.jetty.util.log - Logging initialized @238ms
[Thread-0] INFO spark.embeddedserver.jetty.EmbeddedJettyServer - == Spark has ignited ...
[Thread-0] INFO spark.embeddedserver.jetty.EmbeddedJettyServer - >> Listening on 0.0.0.0:4567
[Thread-0] INFO org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server - jetty-9.3.6.v20151106
[Thread-0] INFO org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector - Started ServerConnector@4be514e0{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:4567}
[Thread-0] INFO org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server - Started @330ms
[main] INFO spark.embeddedserver.jetty.EmbeddedJettyServer - >>> Spark shutting down ...
[main] INFO org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector - Stopped ServerConnector@4be514e0{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:4567}
[main] INFO spark.embeddedserver.jetty.EmbeddedJettyServer - done
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.291 sec

Results :

Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
```

Comment: I don't know if it's the *right method of testing*. Consider posting your question to the Java Spark google group (I hope you'll get a reply...). You may check on Github for addional project contacts.

Comment: I actually posted a question in the google groups too, no activity activations yet.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://sparktutorials.github.io/2015/07/30/spark-testing-unit.html) might help, and it's from the official spark-java website so it might be considered the *right method*, or at least the recommended one.